# Nested classes (or how to "group" properties)

Tags: class, properties, nested, grouping, intellisense

I would like to build a **nested** class hierarchy. Something that would help to **categorize**, let's say **group** objects (mostly properties) by genre while using Intellisense.

*i.e. From* :

```
Class MyHouse
     [+] Property Tv
     [+] Property Kitchen
     [+] Property Radio
     [+] Property Bathroom
     [+] Property Computer
     [+] Property Crib
     [-] Property Bedroom
            Get...
            Set...
         End Property
End class
```

*To* :

```
  Class MyHouse
  |
  |-----Class Rooms
  |         [+] Property Bathroom
  |         [+] Property Bedroom
  |         [+] Property Kitchen
  |         ...
  |
  |-----Class Objects
  |         [+] Property Radio
  |         [+] Property Tv
  |         [+] Property Computer
  |         [+] Property Crib
  |         ...
  |
  End class
```

---

---

**The main objective** is to have **intellisense using the hierarchy**.

```
Dim MyHouse_ as new MyHouse()
         -------------
MyHouse_.| Rooms     |
         | Objects   | 
         -------------
```

---

---

**So** I nested a class within another, and **shared** it's members :

```
 Friend class MyHouse
 |
 |    Friend class Rooms
 |    |
 |    |   Private shared kitchen_ as clsRoom
 |    |   Friend shared Property prop_kitchen
 |    |       Get
 |    |       Set
 |    |   End Property
 |    |   ...
 |    |
 |    End class
 |     ...
 |
 End Class
```

The problem is when I create a new object and want to access it's nested properties, I get the following error :

```
access of shared member constant member qualifying expression will not be evaluated
```

But I don't want to instantiate the sub classes.

**I'm just looking for a good way to have a hierarchy to "organize" the whole class, and directly access it's members.**

**Any way doing this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question :

The proper way to do was simply to 
 - keep both classes separated
 - add a new instance of the sub class in the main parent class

It will look like a field or a property (depending on the declaration done), but it will have this "nested" hierarchy that was my objective.

This allowed me to organize huge classes much nicer
Hope this can help someone